# JQuery create a floating div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, floating

I want to create a floating div using jQuery that allows users to register first before accessing my site. The other part of the page will be disabled unless the user registers. A sample of the div am talking about can be found [here](https://mentor.mara.com/). I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: try http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: you can use a jquery popup plugin eg: bpopup link: http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are talking about modal dialogs

see http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation